# RoomModel class

Tags: c#

I have coded a quick room model system, let me run you should how it exactly works

```
X = 1 square
0 = block square
1 = 1 level higher
2 = 2 levels higher 
and so on...
```

Example, a simple room model structure would be like below:

```
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
XXXXXXXXXX0XX
```

I am just looking for any way to improove it as I am self taught and would like to learn more about how C# can be optimized for better performance.
Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Sahara.Base.Game.Rooms
{
    internal class RoomModel
    {
        private readonly bool _clubOnly;
        private readonly int _doorX;
        private readonly int _doorY;
        private readonly double _doorZ;
        private readonly int _doorDirection;
        private readonly string _modelHeightmap;
        private readonly int _modelSizeX;
        private readonly int _modelSizeY;
        private readonly int _wallHeight;
        private readonly short[,] _squareFloorHeight;
        private readonly byte[,] _squareSeatRotation;
        private readonly SquareState[,] _squareState;
        private readonly string _modelFurniMap;
        private readonly bool _publicPool;
        private readonly byte[,] _roomModelEffects;

        public RoomModel(bool clubOnly, int doorPositionX, int doorPositionY, int wallHeight, double doorPositionZ, int doorDirection, string modelHeightMap, string modelFurniMap, string poolMap)
        {
            _doorX = doorPositionX;
            _doorY = doorPositionY;
            _doorZ = doorPositionZ;
            _doorDirection = doorDirection;
            _wallHeight = wallHeight;
            _modelHeightmap = modelHeightMap.ToLower();
            _modelFurniMap = modelFurniMap;

            if (poolMap != string.Empty)
            {
                _publicPool = true;
                _roomModelEffects = new byte[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            }

            var temporaryHeightmap = _modelHeightmap.Split(Convert.ToChar(13));

            _modelSizeX = temporaryHeightmap[0].Length;
            _modelSizeY = temporaryHeightmap.Length;
            _clubOnly = clubOnly;
            _squareState = new SquareState[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            _squareFloorHeight = new short[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            _squareSeatRotation = new byte[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];

            for (var y = 0; y < _modelSizeY; y++)
            {
                var line = temporaryHeightmap[y];
                line = line.Replace("\r", "");
                line = line.Replace("\n", "");

                var x = 0;
                foreach (var modelSquare in line)
                {
                    if (modelSquare == 'x')
                    {
                        _squareState[x, y] = SquareState.Blocked;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _squareState[x, y] = SquareState.Open;
                        _squareFloorHeight[x, y] = ParseModelSquare(modelSquare);
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }

        public static short ParseModelSquare(char input)
        {

            switch (input)
            {
                case '0':
                    return 0;
                case '1':
                    return 1;
                case '2':
                    return 2;
                case '3':
                    return 3;
                case '4':
                    return 4;
                case '5':
                    return 5;
                case '6':
                    return 6;
                case '7':
                    return 7;
                case '8':
                    return 8;
                case '9':
                    return 9;
                case 'a':
                    return 10;
                case 'b':
                    return 11;
                case 'c':
                    return 12;
                case 'd':
                    return 13;
                case 'e':
                    return 14;
                case 'f':
                    return 15;
                case 'g':
                    return 16;
                case 'h':
                    return 17;
                case 'i':
                    return 18;
                case 'j':
                    return 19;
                case 'k':
                    return 20;
                case 'l':
                    return 21;
                case 'm':
                    return 22;
                case 'n':
                    return 23;
                case 'o':
                    return 24;
                case 'p':
                    return 25;
                case 'q':
                    return 26;
                case 'r':
                    return 27;
                case 's':
                    return 28;
                case 't':
                    return 29;
                case 'u':
                    return 30;
                case 'v':
                    return 31;
                case 'w':
                    return 32;

                default:
                    throw new FormatException("The input was not in a correct format: input must be between (0-k)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've created multiple accounts, please ask for them to be merged: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 9):

One suggestion I'd make:

Instead of having so many fields in your class,  it becomes much easier to write your code, if you break out related fields into sub classes e.g:

```
private class Door
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public double Z;
    public int Direction;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> public static short ParseModelSquare(char input)
> ```

This could use some math to throw away those cases because `char` can be implicitly converted to `int`. See also [Implicit Numeric Conversions Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx).

```
public static short ParseModelSquare(char input)
{
    if ('0' <= input && input <= '9') 
    {
        return (short)(input - '0');
    }

    if ('a' <= input && input <= 'k')
    {
        const int numbersOffset = 10;
        return (short)(input - 'a' + numbersOffset);
    }

    throw new FormatException(..);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get rid of the long switch case like this:

```
public static short ParseModelSquare(char input)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(input))
    {
        return (short) (input - 48);
    }
    if (char.IsLetter(input))
    {
        return (short) (input - 87);
    }
    throw new FormatException("The input was not in a correct format: input must be between (0-k)");
}
```

You can remove all of those variables:

```
private readonly int _wallHeight;
private readonly short[,] _squareFloorHeight;
private readonly byte[,] _squareSeatRotation;
private readonly string _modelFurniMap;
private readonly bool _clubOnly;
private readonly int _doorX;
private readonly int _doorY;
private readonly double _doorZ;
private readonly int _doorDirection;
private readonly bool _publicPool;
private readonly byte[,] _roomModelEffects;
```

But I don't see any use of the things done in the constructor you can probably just leave it empty except for the `SquareState`, unless you have more code.

Answer (score 3):

What's the point of a `RoomModel` class with only private fields?

---

This is waaay too many arguments: `public RoomModel(bool clubOnly, int doorPositionX, int doorPositionY, int wallHeight, double doorPositionZ, int doorDirection, string modelHeightMap, string modelFurniMap, string poolMap)`. Instead, have publicly available properties so your code becomes much clearer:

```
var roomModel = new RoomModel
{
   ClubOnly = clubOnly,
   DoorPositionX = doorPositionX
   // etc.
}
```

This also avoids errors.

---

Your constructor is 50+ lines. That's far too long, IMHO. Some of it should be moved to private methods, but I'd urge you to keep `RoomModel` lean and move the logic in your constructor to a separate "Creator" class.

I'd make `ParseModelSquare()` into a class of its own as well. (Why is this a `public` method?) Perhaps also look at replacing it with a `Dictionary<char, short>()` and finding a more elegant way to fill it instead of a 70 line `switch`.

---

I think you can replace this:

```
var line = temporaryHeightmap[y];
line = line.Replace("\r", "");
line = line.Replace("\n", "");
```

with this:

```
var line = temporaryHeightmap[y].Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
```

This conveys more clearly what you are doing.